# How do I slice a numpy array to get both the first and last two rows

Tags: python, numpy

As far as I can see it, it isn't covered in the [indexing, slicing and iterating](https://web.archive.org/web/20150802020005/http://wiki.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial#head-864862d3f2bb4c32f04260fac61eb4ef34788c4c) scipy tutorial, so let me ask it here:

Say I've

```
x = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,0]])
x: array([[1, 2],
          [3, 4],
          [5, 6],
          [7, 8],
          [9, 0]])
```

How do I slice the array in order get both the first and last rows:

```
y: array([[1, 2],
          [3, 4],              
          [7, 8],
          [9, 0]])
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know if there's a slick way to do that.  You could list the indices explicitly, of course:

```
>>> x[[0,1,-2,-1]]
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [7, 8],
       [9, 0]])
```

Or use `r_` to help, which would probably be more convenient if we wanted more rows from the head or tail:

```
>>> x[np.r_[0:2, -2:0]]
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [7, 8],
       [9, 0]])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I found that `np.vstack((x[0:2,:],x[-2:,:]))` is even quicker. I can't really understand why, but your solution is definitely more elegant.

Comment: If performance is an issue, you might want to try `np.concatenate([x[:2], x[-2:]])` too, to see how it performs.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively,you can use indices to remove as

```
mask = np.ones(len(x), dtype=np.bool)
mask[2:3] = False # that you want to remove
y = x[mask]
```